# Select * into SqlserverTable2 from SqlExpressTable1, can this be done

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

Can I Select * into a Sqlserver Table from a  SqlExpress Table the way I can from a Sqlserver Table to a Sqlserver Table using

```
Select * into  Table2 from  Table1
```

If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Are the tables on the same SqlServer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are distinct servers, so you would need to introduce a linked server, on the server where you intend to make a reference to the other server.

```
  sp_addlinkedserver @server= 'some_ip_or_URI',  @srvproduct= 'SQL Server'
```

Then you need to use the full name of the table/object needed in the query

```
  [Server Name].[Database Name].[Owner/Schema Name].[Object Name]
```

as in

```
 [test.private.mydomain.com].ClientDB.dbo.tblInvoices
```

Note the square brackets which are necessary of course, when the instance/server name include dots, spaces and such characters.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will first have to link the two SQL Server instances together first.
The form you'd use after that would be:

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE2 FROM [ServerInstanceName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ssms database import. Couldn't get the naming to work using select.